# Powershell datetime parseexact issue with month being reduced to one digit

Tags: powershell

My datetime string, 01042024, is in the format MM dd yyyy.

I am parsing the extract using the code below:

```
$testdateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact("01042024", "MMddyyyy", $null)
Write-host $testdateTime
```

The code mentioned above functions properly and generates the following output:

```
1/4/2024 12:00:00 AM
```

However, it is throwing an issue when the string 1042024 is used (the month is now reduced to one digit):
[image]

I have attempted to use the code below, but the same problem keeps occurring:

```
$testdateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact("1042024", "Mddyyyy", $null)
Write-host $testdateTime
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you've toadd the logic to pad a `0` to months which are single digit. There is no other way I guess. For ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: ParseExact can use a array for the format [DateTime]::ParseExact("01042024", @("MMddyyyy","Mddyyyy") , $null)

Comment: @jdweng: Mddyyyy format is not working for 1042024 string btw.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "Mddyyyy" is that 3 months are still 2 digits in size: 10, 11, and 12.  This creates a ambiguous situation where a leading 1 could be for January, October, November, or December.

AFAIK, you will need to pad the left side of a string with a zero if the string is 7 characters long, as in the following code:

```
$DTStr = "1042024"
$testdateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($DTStr.PadLeft(8,'0'), "MMddyyyy", $null)
$testdateTime
```

Unfortunately, the above code would have problems if the string was somehow only 6 characters in length due to the fact that it would pad "`00`" to the beginning of the string.  But, if you are sure this situation would never hapen, then this would work for you.